# Annoying persistence of MessageBox on screen after OK button is clicked

Tags: c#, video, messagebox

a problem with C# program in my pc :when open a lot messagebox one after the other  (for example because of the press of a button 3 or 4 times ) the last messagebox remains uncomfortably on the screen, just as inactive image and sometimes broken and incomplete. One example of these ghost MessageBox here :

https://imageshack.com/i/jmawh3j

Peraphs because of low memory of video card in my pc?
 Thanks

Comment: Whatever that is behind the message box is not refreshing.  If it's yours, call its `Invalidate()` or similar.

Comment: The problem is the form IN FRONT that does not disappear.

Comment: The form is gone.  The drawing surface is not refreshing, leaving the ghost image.  Can you click it and drag it around?  No?  Then it's _gone_.

Comment: Yes,is gone.....Now i have tried with this.InvalidateVisual() and this.UpdateLayout() ,but dont work.   Tankyou

Comment: RESOLVED: I have put this istruction  "System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();"     after each MessageBox.Show(...)  istruction.   Bye